# Where can I download the latest 64-bit edition of Sonicwall SSL-VPN NetExtender for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, vpn, 64-bit, sonicwall

Does anyone know where to download the latest edition of the 64-bit version of SonicWall SSL-VPN NetExtender for Windows 7?

Comment: Do you have a mysonicwall.com login? The download should be available there.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, WWW.mysonicwall.com has what you need.  Hit the downloads link, then the 'free downloads' tab.   The dropdown should then have an option for netextender.

Comment: It looks like this is no longer accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select your device in the dropdown in the download center. Then you should get a list of NetExtender versions. You will use the same version for 64-bit version of Windows 7 as 32-bit version btw.

Answer (score -3):

As of August 27, 2015 it can not be downloaded from http://www.mysonicwall.com/  On the mysonicwall web site, the netextender has been replaced with Global VPN Client which does not have the same options and will not connect to the VPN server I need it to.

I was able to succesfully get installed, but, it was very complicated.

The method that netextender uses for installing is by hacking your computer through web browser, I know this sounds bizarre but, I was able to get it installed.

Chrome has been patched so this hack will not work, so you need to use a browswer were security is not important.  Obviously Internet Explorer is the best choice for this.

From Internet Explorer go to the gateway address provided by your adminstrators, log in using your vpn credentials, then you will be offered an option for netextender.

My Internet Explorer was from a fully updated Windows 7 fresh install.  This version of windows was ubable to install directly, but, there was an option for "all downloads" where I was able to download a normal installer and install the netextender just like it was not a peice of shit.

I hope that someone can re-write my installation instructions in a politially correct way.  I realize that calling sonicwall a piece of shit is not friendly, but, since I've been looking and looking for instructions and all of the politically corrrect folks have been unsucessful, you get when I offer.